# USB Connection notification

Tags: android

can we receive notification if user connected there phone through USB cable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajay,

I wasn't able to find anything specific to just "USB Connected," but there are a few Broadcast Actions that may be of interest in this case depending on what you are trying to accomplish:

- [`ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED):  External media is unmounted because it is being shared via USB mass storage.
- [`ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED): The device has entered USB Mass Storage mode. This is used mainly for the USB Settings panel.
- [`ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED): The device has exited USB Mass Storage mode. This is used mainly for the USB Settings panel.

There doesn't seem to be a Broadcast Action specific to USB simply being plugged in, you could also try doing something with:

- [`ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED): External power has been connected to the device.

But this would go off for both USB connected to a computer and USB connect ONLY to a power source...

Interestingly, I also found this [LINK](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/771f07ead3c635c5) simply stating that there was no Broadcast Action for "USB Connected".

You may be out of luck in this case :-\

Comment: Thanks willylate, at least i get a direction to do research an d it is very useful.

Comment: good luck.  if you manage to find an undocumented method to receiving a USB connected action, please report your findings in your original question.

Comment: Seems like ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED has stopped being sent in later versions of Android (at least from ICS). However, from Gingerbread on you can listen for "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE", this is broadcast whenever the USB connection is made, at least as far as my experimentation goes. There's a boolean extra, "connected", to tell you whether it's connected or disconnected. So if you listen for both that and ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED etc, your code should work on all versions.

Comment: Also, none of these will work if you are trying to detect a USB fault, e.g. if the USB power connection is fine, but the USB data connections are faulty.

Comment: @chrisdowney incidentally, I can't find documentation on "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" anywhere, any pointers?  For some reason it doesn't seem to exist in 2.3.3, but does in 2.3.4, even though both are reportedly Gingerbread.

Comment: @michael I don't think there is any documentation for that, I found it by looking at the android code.

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is one broadcast event; if you turned on Debug in your application settings, your will see a bug on your notification bar when you plugged usb. Following is the sample how it works;

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE -> "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" actually
    if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        // UsbManager.USB_CONNECTED -> "connected" actually
        usbConnected = extras.getBoolean(UsbManager.USB_CONNECTED);
        ...
```

You can find this at framework/base/service/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since: API Level 5
An activity to run when device is inserted into a car dock. Used with ACTION_MAIN to launch an activity. For more information, see UiModeManager.
Constant Value: "android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK"
public static final String CATEGORY_CAR_MODE

Since: API Level 8
Used to indicate that the activity can be used in a car environment.
Constant Value: "android.intent.category.CAR_MODE"

Answer (score 0):

A number of years later... this might help someone that came looking like I did. Since Honeycomb, there are two actions one can listen for `USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and `USB_DEVICE_DETACHED`.

Comment: As far as I know, these are intended for USB OTG devices (where Android acts as the host), not for connections where Android connects to a host.

Comment: That’s right. In my case, it was exactly what I was looking for (I had an external USB camera) and I couldn’t find any other answers, so I thought I’d leave this here in case it helps someone.