# detecting the mounting of the sdcard

Tags: android, mount, android-sdcard

I am new to android .. Can anyone tell me how to detect if my device is connected through USB to my personal computer.I want to achieve this programatically

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522963/usb-connection-notification

Answer (score 1):

You can find all you need on this documentation page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()