# Get Broadcast when USB cable is connected

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [USB Connection notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522963/usb-connection-notification)

What to do in resource XML file and in manifest if I want to get broadcast for all USB cables.
Currently the resource XML file is like this:

```
<resources>
<usb-accessory manufacturer="Acme, Inc" model="Whiz Banger" version="7.0" />
</resources>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5523092/603233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiverClassName">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Modify you onReceive inside yourReceiverClassName to this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED"))
{
    Log.d(TAG,"USB connected..");
}

if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED"))
{
     Log.d(TAG,"USB connected..");
}
```

}

Comment: Working perfectly but in ics or above i can't able to get this broadcast until i open my application. what i suppose to do if i don't want to put any activity in my application.