# Manifest.xml, intent-filter and USB accessories

Tags: android, usb, android-manifest, adt

I currently have the following in my Manifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </activity>
```

Right now this will attempt to launch my application when a USB accessory is attached.

What changes do I need to make so that the application does NOT try to launch when an accessory is attached (assumed it is already launched) yet still will recognize the accessory when plugged in to the USB port?

Comment: I did not understand `What changes do I need to make so that the application does NOT try to launch when an accessory is attached (assumed it is already launched) yet still will recognize the accessory when plugged in to the USB port?` part of your question, please elaborate.

Comment: I don't want the application to auto-launch when a USB accessory is attached. But the application should still recognize usb accessories.

Comment: I haven't tested yet but it seems this might be a better solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a `Service/Intent Service` that will be started instead of the Activity from the Application and you can perform the tasks in the Background.
A Broadcast Event occurs when USB is attached. You can simply receive it using the following code template.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
String action = intent.getAction();
// UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE -> "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE" actually
if (action.equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_STATE)) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    // UsbManager.USB_CONNECTED -> "connected" actually
    usbConnected = extras.getBoolean(UsbManager.USB_CONNECTED);
```

Source : [USB Connection notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522963/usb-connection-notification) 
I hope this helps.
        ...