# OTG Usb Coonnector intent

Tags: android, android-intent

in my app i need to detect the empty otg insert . The system detects the empty usb connector by this and showing it notification like image below 
[Notification Image](http://imgh.us/2016-09-15_14.10.04.png)

I need to recive its intent . I tried following code

```
<receiver android:name=".Otg">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

( This reciver is inside an activity )

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "connected" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "disconnected" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        }
```

Nothing toasted on connect or disconnected . 
Also i tried these intents in my activity applicstion manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
                </intent-filter>
```

How can i recive that ?
Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522963/usb-connection-notification), @chrisdowney made the following comment:

> Seems like `ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED` has stopped being sent in later
>   versions of Android (at least from ICS). However, from Gingerbread on
>   you can listen for `"android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"`, this is
>   broadcast whenever the USB connection is made, at least as far as my
>   experimentation goes. There's a boolean extra, `"connected"`, to tell
>   you whether it's connected or disconnected. So if you listen for both
>   that and `ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED` etc, your code should work on all
>   versions. – chrisdowney Jun 22 '12 at 21:46

See if that solves your problem. If so, please upvote his comment ;-)

Comment: I think that works only when otg is loaded on device . What im looking for is same intent that device use to create that notification when inserting an EMPTY otg connector . Thanks for your information . I will upvote anyway